# Sitecore Update Installation Wizard never ends

Tags: upgrade

Currently I have Sitecore 8.0 Update-1 and I want it to upgrade to 8.2. 
So as per the 8.2 upgrade guide, prerequisites for running this update is Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003 (Initial Release) or later.

So I first decide to upgrade my current Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1.

As per the 8.1 upgrade guide, I have started to install the **Sitecore Update Installation Wizard 1.0.0 rev.150930** but this update installation wizard never ends. I have tried 3 times. One wizard took more than 24 hrs but it never ends.

I am following the upgrade guide (Sitecore 8.1) step by step but still facing this issue.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you check the upgradehistory logs? `Website\temp\__UpgradeHistory` should have the log information. Do you see any issues there?

Comment: In Website\temp, there is file or folder with the name of __upgradehistory.

Comment: @JaideepCharan you should see inside Website\temp\__UpgradeHistory mentioned by phani a file named InstallationLog.txt. Can you check and update the question?

Comment: Do you have MongoDB installed/configured? Or have disabled analytics?

Answer (score 3):

As Hdvti mentioned I've seen this when you have xDB enabled. As a workaround disable it in short term using the following patch file and then re-move the patch file after you have installed any modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="Xdb.Enabled">
                <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
            </setting>
            <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled">
                <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
            </setting>
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have xDB enabled? If yes, make sure Mongo Daemon Service is running. And check in the Sitecore data/logs for any MongoDB exceptions. I have run into this issue in past and turned out that Mongo Daemon wasnt running and that was causing interruptions in installing Sitecore updates/packages.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in my previous 7.2 to 8.2 upgrade.

In my case while executing the Upgrade Wizard (X version to Y), it goes fine till all steps and stuck on the last step, where basically it tries to delete temp files and copy new files. The wizard stucks here for hours until we close the browser.

Troubleshooting and call with Sitecore support helped me came up with various possible reasons blogged here. Please have a look and try the options:

https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2017/02/08/first-blog-post/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find an error in the `Website \ temp \ __ UpgradeHistory`, try first upgrade to a higher version of 8.0.x and after then try an upgrade to version 8.1.x.

I have solved the same problem in one of our customers, where we have upgraded to version 8.0-update5 and after then we upgraded to version 8.1.x.

I'm not quite sure, but maybe it will help you too.

Best regards, Jiri Semrad

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue too. When I installed it, it would not stop spinning but the logs showed that the installation was complete. In my case I just refreshed the page and confirmed that the installation succeeded which was the case

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue before.

In my case giving application pool user permissions to Data folder fixed it.

In my case its trying to create packages folder in data folder and failing.